# Flutter Firebase no notification shown on terminated app

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase cloud messaging for flutter. Everything works as expected, when the app is either open or in the background. But if I close the app (terminated) no messages are received.

I send the messages with the firebase console.

I have tried two emulators, that both had play services installed.I even logged in with a google account in the emulator.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `priority` to `high` and it started working. The docs only talk about priority high in the context of data messages but it seems it is important for notifications as well then.

Comment: how do you set it to high? I created a separate channel and set the importance to max but still no luck

Comment: Well depends on how you send the message to Firebase... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801818/how-i-can-specify-the-priority-on-fcm-message

Comment: priority to high already set, but still can't receive any app terminated notifications!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested 4 cases and found that:

- In debug mode, when app is terminated, **Android won't show**, iOS shows
- In release mode, both Android and iOS show as normal